# Posting a link video on facebook using koala

Tags: facebook, koala

I am using the following command to post a video link from youtube into facebook:

```
client.put_wall_post options[:message].text, {
    :name => "Type O Negative",
    :link => "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E67D-ZCuoEw",
    :description => "Type O Negative"} , "me"
```

It works fine and facebook displays the first thumb for this image which is http://img.youtube.com/vi/E67D-ZCuoEw/1.jpg

[image]

But i want the second thumb: http://img.youtube.com/vi/E67D-ZCuoEw/2.jpg

[image]

So i pass the :picture argument as follows:

```
client.put_wall_post options[:message].text, {
    :name => "Type O Negative",
    :link => "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E67D-ZCuoEw",
    :picture = > "http://img.youtube.com/vi/E67D-ZCuoEw/2.jpg",  
    :description => "Type O Negative"} , "me"
```

Doing this facebook does not recognizes my link as a embedded video and just shows the thumb with a link to the youtube page.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `put_picture` from the Koala API?

http://rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/Koala/Facebook/GraphAPIMethods#put_picture-instance_method

Despite its name, it apparently operates just the same for video.

Like you, I have used `put_wall_post` and it works fine for a basic link, but you might consider using something more specific from the API.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use URI like http://www.youtube.com/v/E67D-ZCuoEw instead of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E67D-ZCuoEw